# codenameone is there any known issue in NativeConnectivityImpl

Tags: codenameone

Hi  I see following crash report on google play store. I'm wondering is there any known issue related to NativeConnectivityImpl.Please advise.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at org.b.a.c.a (NativeConnectivityImpl.java:39)
  at org.b.a.d.a (NativeConnectivityStub.java:9)
  at org.b.a.a.b (Connectivity.java:44)
  at org.b.a.a.a (Connectivity.java:40)
  at com.xxxxxxx.xxx.b.n.k (ServerImpl.java:1255)
  at com.xxxxxxx.xxx.b.n.a (ServerImpl.java:1198)
  at com.xxxxxxx.xxx.c.a$1.run (TrackLocation.java:48)
  at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop (Timer.java:555)
  at java.util.TimerThread.run (Timer.java:505)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a library we published and it doesn't change unless you explicitly update it. This is a behavioral change in Android.

I [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/codenameone-connectivity/pull/2) to the author of the cn1lib who might fix it.

Comment: I see the merge is complete.  is it ready? or do I have to wait to give the build.

Comment: Libraries aren't updated automatically. It should be re-built by the author (or by you) and updated. Ideally the author would submit a pull request with the rebuilt library to https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOneLibs/ and then you can update the library from the Extension Manager

Comment: I don't see the update extension manager. Is there a way we can follow-up on this. Thanks

Comment: This wasn't submitted. I suggest filing an issue to the author or compiling your own cn1lib